# Android getDir() with MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE does not work

Tags: android, internal, file-access

I want to be able to edit a file stored in the app internal memory accessible via [Context.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with any available external text editor by launching `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with type `"text/plain"` and the file URI as the argument. While external editors work well with files on the sdcard, they are not able to access files under [Context.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

I am invoking `getDir()` as `Context.getDir("data", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)` but I still get access denied error when passing the URI to external editors via the intent.

According to the docs passing [`MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) to `getDir()` should be sufficient to enable other apps access and modify the file but this does not seem to be the case. Or am I missing something?

So the question is how to enable other apps to modify specific files under `/data/data/app.package/` without creating a copy of the file on sdcard or resorting to root super powers?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own API to achieve that.

For example, you create your own library and which will access your internal file and other application will access that library. You can even use broadcast receiver or other means you feel right for this purpose.

Alternatively you can design a content provider for that too.

Another way would be if you create file using these command `Context.getExternalCacheDir()`  or `Context.getExternalFilesDir(type)`, file will be created on SD card which you will be able to access using a direct path.

Comment: My question is primarily about why `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` does not work as expected.